# Pointers in C with arrays

Tags: c, pointers

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int c[4][4] = {{0,1,2,3},{4,5,6,7},{8,9,10,11},{12,13,14,15}};
    int (*p)[3] = (int(*)[3])(c+2);
    return 0;
}
```

Its interesting that it sets p to be:
{{8,9,10},{11,12,13},{14,15,-8224}}

I do not understand what is happening, especially in the 6th line of the code. Please help me!

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to understand what is happening in a piece of code that doesn't do anything and is written in a way that nobody ever should write code?

Comment: `(int(*)[3])` is a *cast*, to a pointer to an array of three integers. While the expression `c+2` is equal to `&c[2]`, which is a pointer to the third element of `c`.

Comment: Yes, I need to know because, surprisingly it sets p to be {{8,9,10}, {11, 12, 13}, {14,15,0}}.

Comment: No it doesn't. `p` is a pointer. All that line does is set the *address* that pointer holds. How that pointer is *typed* dictates how *you* see what it claims lives at the address it holds. (and its lying, btw, because that's exactly what you asked it to do).

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I'm sure it was for purely academic reasons of course `:)`

Comment: Your code never does anything with the value of `p`. How are you determining that it "sets p to be" those values?

Comment: Posting code like this is depressing.  Please don't do it.  How could it possibly be of any use to future SO users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int c[4][4]` declares a 2D array with dimensions 4x4.

`int (*p)[3]` declares an array pointer to an array of 3 elements.

`(int(*)[3])(c+2)` invokes a pointer aliasing bug, by treating the address of `c+2` as if there was an array of 3 elements there.

Pointer conversions between type `int (*)[4]` (the type of `c+2`) and type `int(*)[3]` are not safe. In practice, most compilers will likely give you some deterministic result from this code, but they are not required to do so. The program may as well crash and burn and then that's the programmer's fault.

Comment: I think it's unclear whether there is an aliasing bug. `(int(*)[3])(c+2)` certainly is not an aliasing bug , it's a cast. I guess you mean that subsequently reading `p[0][0]` might be an aliasing bug. However that is an lvalue of type `int` and it is accessing an object of type `int` which does not violate the strict aliasing rule. The standard is vague here.   (Certainly there is an out of bounds access bug)

Comment: @M.M I'll have to assume that they did the cast because they actually want to use the variable somewhere. The pointed-to type will be an array, not an int. As far as I understand it, an array of 3 elements is not compatible with an array of 4 elements. Also another concern might be alignment, in case `int` is a smaller type than the alignment requirement. Anyway the point is: just don't write weird code this.

Comment: @M.M What about the first dereference? p[0] is a different type than c[0]. That is a violation of aliasing.

Comment: @2501 `p[0]` is not used to access an object (i.e. lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on `p[0]` doesn't fetch anything, it just does pointer decay)

Comment: @M.M I think you're right. Then the only problem with this is the pointer conversion, which may not be correctly aligned or create a trap value.

Comment: Yeah. I don't think it can be a trap value but in theory it could be incorrectly aligned.

Comment: @M.M It could happen if sizeof isn't the same.